# ¿Por qué las palabras "hombre" y "gente" tienen diferente raíz?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, plurales, comparación-de-idiomas, nombres-colectivos

"**Hombre**" en español se refiere a cualquier persona (hombre y mujer) y también, en ocasiones, a una persona de género exclusivamente masculino.

En inglés es igual: la palabra "**man**" puede referirse a hombre o mujer (*man, person, human, individual, human being, fellow*).

Sin embargo la palabra "**gente**" es el múltiple de "hombre" (cuando se refiere a persona de cualquier género).

Usualmente las palabras singulares y plurales tienen la misma raíz, pero esto no sucede con las palabras "**hombre**" / "**gente**".

Lo mismo se repite en otros idiomas, como el ruso, donde es:

```
Человек - hombre (en el sentido de cualquier persona, sin importar el género)
Люди - gente
```

Igual: son raíces totalmente distintas.

Comment: la palabra "hombre" en mi pregunta se refiere a cualquier persona, sin importar el genero.

Comment: La palabra hombre debe tener diferente raiz, por que antiguamente tenia significado diferente.

Comment: no entiendo la pregunta ¿Por qué iban a tener la misma raiz si son palabras diferentes?

Comment: In careful English man only refers to a male member of Homo sapiens. The gender neutral term is person.

Comment: @mdewey - In German OP's point about *man* is super clear.  But he's right, *man* can mean *person* in English.  See Definition 2 in https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/man.

Comment: @aparente001 German?

Comment: @pablodf76 - What are you asking, sorry?  What I'm saying is that in German it's more obvious than in English that "man" has that other meaning.  Does that help?

Answer (score 5):

La palabra *hombre* en castellano, igual que *man* en inglés, son genéricas, pero en los últimos tiempos se prefiere usar palabras realmente neutras, como en castellano *persona*, cuyo plural es regular, *personas*.

La palabra *gente* no es un plural irregular de *hombre* o de *persona*. Es un sustantivo singular colectivo que significa "grupo de personas". Proviene del latín *[gēns](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gens#Latin)*, que significa "clan, tribu" o también "familia". En castellano podríamos decir siempre *personas* pero muchas veces preferimos decir *gente*.

Esto no sólo ocurre con personas sino también con animales donde los machos y las hembras son considerados muy diferentes (por su forma, su conducta o su uso). Existen las palabras *toro* y *vaca* pero no hay un plural que las una; para hablar de un grupo de toros y vacas decimos *[ganado](http://dle.rae.es/?id=IpmVKGf)* (o especificamos: *ganado [bovino](http://dle.rae.es/?id=60KVyKV)*).

Supongo que ocurre lo mismo en otros idiomas por las mismas razones.

Comment: Incluso la palabra *hombre* se usa como el conjunto de la humanidad, o de la gente de una época: _El hombre ha llegado a la Luna_

Comment: Sí, el significado es ligeramente diferente. Es llamativo que uno puede decir *el hombre de la Antigüedad* o *el hombre de la Edad Moderna* (donde *hombre* y *gente* son intercambiables) pero no puede decir con el mismo sentido genérico *el hombre en Argentina* o *el hombre de Francia* (donde sí puede hacerlo con *gente*).

Comment: Gente y hombre son dos palabras distintas, ambas provienen del latin, sin embargo su uso se ha homologado debido a sus similitudes.